# How to make images change shape with window size

Tags: html, css

i have inserted images into my html code and styled them to fit underneath a section of text. How do i make it so my images shrink and enlarge based on the size of the window? What would i need to add to my CSS to enable this?
Many Thanks

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyKrg.png)

[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCnl2.png)

Comment: Use a `media query`.

Comment: Im not 100% read up on media queries so i may be incorrect saying this but wouldnt this just change the layout/placement of the images when resized? what i want to do is change the scale of the images in relation to the window size if that makes sense?

Comment: set `object-fit: contain` and `max-width: 100%` to your `img`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of px on width use % automatically will change itself when resize the window